# Violation of the Permissions policy - expo react native app removed from play console

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console

A change of policy has been made at google play console and I started getting these weird email notifying me that my app was removed -

> "We only allow apps to access Call Log or SMS data for permitted uses
>   and only to enable the app’s core functionality."

Thing is that I have any of these permission requests neither in my app.json nor I have any library requesting such a thing (I pretty sure). 
Under permission in my `app.json` I tried adding `"ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"` instead of leaving that empty, because I read somewhere that it prevents expo from requesting default (`READ_SMS`) permissions, but it didn't work.

Also, I didn't see anywhere where it says that the lib react-native-phone-call requests either of these above permissions.

**my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.21",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.5.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-timer-countdown": "^2.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typeface-raleway": "0.0.54"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

**my app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./....png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/SplashScreen.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "facebookAppId": ".....",
    "facebookDisplayName": "....",
    "facebookScheme": "...",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "15",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": ".......",
      "infoPlist": {
      "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes": ["fbapi", "fb-messenger-share-api", "fbauth2", "fbshareextension"]
      }
    },
    "android": {
    "versionCode": 15,
    "package": "....",
    "permissions":[]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its a new policy buy google they won't allow you to do in app phone calls and texting without very specific permissions, basically you have to be a messing app to get approved, they are retroactivly removing any app from the store that has the permission in their xml but that does not comply with the new rules

Comment: But they don't mention making phone calls as part of the permission list. I didn't request access to call logs nor to reading sms. I don't understand where does it state in my app that I request that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"permissions":[]` you can use `"permissions": ["WAKE_LOCK"]`